# Fasm declare structure in stack

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, structure, fasm

I cant declate the structure in the stack rightly in fasm for some reason. Here is the problem, let's say i have this structure:

```
struct IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER 
  _Name db IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME dup (?) 
  union 
    PhysicalAddress     dd ? 
    VirtualSize         dd ? 
  ends 
  VirtualAddress        dd ? 
  SizeOfRawData         dd ? 
  PointerToRawData      dd ? 
  PointerToRelocations  dd ? 
  PointerToLinenumbers  dd ? 
  NumberOfRelocations   dw ? 
  NumberOfLinenumbers   dw ? 
  Characteristics       dd ? 
ends
```

As i understand, to declare this in stack i need to write something like this:

```
start:

virtual at esp+N
  section IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER
end virtual  

lea eax, [section]
```

Where **N** is supposed to be the size of the structure, but how can i get the structure size?  There is no sizeof as far as i know, do i need to calculate every structure size manually to declare it inside the stack memory? Also, how can i declare it inside the stack frame using macro?

Answer (score 0):

you do not need this N, the structure starts at esp and is N bytes long. You just have to allocate this structure on the stack, so this should work:

```
start:
virtual at esp
  @@:
  section IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER
  IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER_SIZE = $ - @b
end virtual  
sub esp, IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER_SIZE ;allocate local buffer
lea eax, [section]
...
add esp, IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER_SIZE ;;free local buffer
```